# IIS SMTP TLS encryption issue

Tags: iis, smtp, tls

I enabled TLS in IIS SMTP Virtual Server with a self-signed server certificate. Made sure that the certificate has the FQDN of the server. Checked the TLS encryption checkbox in Virtual SMTP > Properties > Delivery tab > Outbound Security.

When I try to send mail using Pickup folder in c:\inetpub\mailroot the email does not get delivered with TLS. Also, the TLS encryption checkbox becomes unchecked automatically.

Do you know what might be causing this problem?

Regards John

Comment: Seems to be configuration problem, this can help
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4014125/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-for-outgoing-tls-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Access tab.  If the certificate is installed correctly then you should see a message in the Secure Communication area that says "A TLS certificate is found with expiration date: xx/xx/xxxx"  If you don't see that message then you need to make sure the TLS certificate is installed correctly.  See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7f531c81-a5a7-45fa-9f22-e2aa440770d7/tls-certificate-issue?forum=winservergen) for certificate generation and installation.

Comment: The certificate was correct and I could see the message. I am checking another option and if it works will post it